# How to create log for power point 2007 using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am creating a Add-in for power point; In which it will perform all Quality checkes like standard font format, spell-check, grammar-check, standard template etc. Means if the font is "calibri" in some slid and "Times Roman" in others then it will convert it into "Arial"(which is my standard format).

So basically i want to create one log file which contains this type of changes made by macro.

logically i want to track the "change event" like spell-check or change in font format or size. So when the macro runs then at the end it will show the list of changes has been made in PPT.

So any logic or suggestion or code will be appreciate.
Thanks

Comment: If you want the macro to make one run through the file and make all necessary changes, logging would be as simple as appending some text to a global string variable and then displaying it/writing it to file/whatever at the end of the run.  Tracking, responding and logging changes to fonts, bolding and such would be MUCH more complex; there are no events for this kind of change.  You'd have to respond to the SelectionChange event, work out what's been selected and what it's formatting is, then compare that with what it all is when the user selects something else.

Comment: thanks steve. i will try to build the code from your logic.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a little bit to get you started.

```
Sub Undo_Invalid_Entry()    
If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then    
If IsNumeric(Target) = False Then    
Application.EnableEvents = False    
Application.Undo    
End If    
End If    
Application.EnableEvents = True    
End Sub
```

(from [here](http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2009/01/how-to-undo-last-action-using-excel-vba.html))

Then just store it into a file.

Comment: Hi AT, Thanks for quick reply. but i am coding it in powerpoint not in excel. So please post code for power point.

Comment: Because as per above code, Target.Address = "$A$2" will not work in ppt. and basically i want to track the changes which macro will do during run.